# How to include Matlab outputs in Latex?

Tags: matlab, latex

I knew I can use "mcode" to include Matlab scripts in Latex, for example:

```
\begin{lstlisting}
clear, clc 
load('Data.mat');
\end{lstlisting}
```

but how can I do with the Matlab script outputs? Many thanks

Comment: Just to be clear... you're interested in the *output* from MATLAB, but that has to be done from *within* LaTeX?

Comment: Yes. I want to include the outputs of some Matlab scripts, formatted,  in Latex. But don't know how to do it

Comment: You should have a look at the [`matlab-prettifier`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/matlab-prettifier) package; it improves upon `mcode` in many ways. See [this answer](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/158816/21891), for instance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The [`mcode` package](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/8015-m-code-latex-package) uses [`listings`](http://ctan.org/pkg/listings) to set up the appropriate formatting. In fact, the following is taken from `mcode.sty`:

```
%%   PLEASE NOTE that this package does nothing but save you from
%%   figuring out some configurations  in setting up the LISTINGS
%%   package. ALL the work is done by that package!  Thus, please
%%   refer your questions to the listings package documentation.
```

So, after loading `mcode`, input the listing using `\lstinputlisting{<file>}`:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{filecontents}% http://ctan.org/pkg/filecontents
\usepackage[framed,numbered,autolinebreaks,useliterate]{mcode}
\begin{filecontents*}{mscript.mat}
function y = myfun(aa, sigma, options)

  sigma

  y = aa .* pdf('logn', aa, -0.5*sigma^2, sigma)

  %y = 1/(sigma.*sqrt(2.*pi)) .* exp((-((log(aa)+0.5*sigma.^2)).^2) ./ (2.*sigma.^2));
\end{filecontents*}
\begin{document}
\lstinputlisting{mscript.mat}
\end{document}
```

The above example was taken from [Inserting MATLAB code in the appendix](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/75116/5764).

---

For insertion of MATLAB output, I'd suggest the `verbatim` environment:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
\begin{verbatim}
>> A = [16 3 2 13; 5 10 11 8; 9 6 7 12; 4 15 14 1]
A =
 16  3  2 13
  5 10 11  8
  9  6  7 12
  4 15 14  1

>> A(2,3)
ans =
 11
\end{verbatim}
\end{document}
```